# Check whether the user has a valid credentials Jira rest API

Tags: javascript, npm, jira-rest-api

I am using [jira-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jira-client) npm module to make API calls on my jira instance, I want to check that if the user has a valid credentials before doing anything else, depending on that I would either:

- Tell the user that they don't have a valid username or token.
- or Let the user use the project functionalities

is that possible? I am able to make calls and with invalid credentials I will got response with a special message, but I want to know if there is a specific call for checking username and token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using normal fetch we can use

```
https://myJiraInstance/rest/auth/1/session
```

but for jira-client module it seems there is no way, however we can use `findproject` method in this way we can make sure that the user has a valid credentials as well as have access to the project itself.

If there any other solution I would be happy to have it.